# Possible to Specify a Parameter For AWS Athena Query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I did some research and haven't yet found if this is possible, but does anyone know if you can specify a parameter for an AWS Athena Query?

For example, I want my query to be able to filter `WHERE merchant_id = {merchant_id}`. Is it possible to specify this so that I could use the same query for every merchant I want? And if so, where would I pass in the input to the Athena query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One cannot set variables with AWS Athena. Since Athena can run only one query in a session.

If you try to run more than one query you will get the following error.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Apologies for my original post not being super clear. I only need Athena to run one query in a session, but I was hoping to be able to pass in a parameter so that the query would work for any merchant I want. So I would run the query multiple times (multiple sessions) but I wanted to pass in a different merchant every time. Do you know if this is possible? Thanks!

Comment: In a regular sql, setting the parameter is a separate sql statement and those data is stored for that transaction. It is not the same here. You can run via command line by passing parameters or programattically, but still you will be forming a single query upfront. So, it is not possible to pass parameters to Athena Queries atleast as of now.

Answer (score 7):

I appreciate this thread is a little old, but it's one of the first results I found when trying to do the same.  I'm not sure if there would be significant performance issues, and I'm certain it can be improved upon, but the theory is as follows:

Using Athena's accepted WITH function, create a couple of queries to hold your variables, join these to your original query/table and then use them within the filters.

```
WITH startdate AS (SELECT DATE('2019-12-01') AS v_startdate),
enddate AS (SELECT DATE('2019-12-31') AS v_enddate)
SELECT *SQL HERE* FROM table_name
LEFT JOIN startdate ON 1=1
LEFT JOIN enddate ON 1=1
WHERE table_name.start_date >= v_startdate
AND table_name.end_date <= v_enddate
```

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is not correct anymore. The new v2 query engine for Athena allows for "prepared statements".

`prepare my_statement from select * from some_table where variable_to_change = ?`

Then, you can execute the prepared statement by passing in a live value like:

`execute my_statement using 3`

This would execute the above `select` statement with `variable_to_change=3`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-with-prepared-statements.html

Comment: Thanks for this -- this is how one can check Athena engine version, since v1 might still be in use: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/engine-versions.html

Answer (score 0):

This is possible from AWS Wrangler (or AWS SDK for Pandas, its new official name). Your query would be, in python:

```
import awswrangler as wr

wr.athena.read_sql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM <your_table> WHERE merchant_id = :merchant_id;",
    database="<your_database>",
    params={
        "merchant_id": 2,
    },
)
```

BEWARE: contrary to classical SQL, named parameters end up with semicolons. Moreover, string parameters must be enclosed with single quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM <your_table> WHERE merchant_label = ':merchant_label;'
```